# What is the proper way to build emacs with pdumper in fedora?

Tags: fedora, xorg, gnome3, emacs

I am trying to build the latest emacs with pdumper, but I don't know if I am doing it right.

First I clone it from here https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/emacs.git then checkout the `pdumper` branch. Then tried to configure it with just `--without-makeinfo` flag. Then it hit a point that it requires me a library then I retry it, then install again other libraries, until I reach this

```
checking for library containing tputs... no
configure: error: The required function 'tputs' was not found in any library.
The following libraries were tried (in order):
  libtinfo, libncurses, libterminfo, libcurses, libtermcap
Please try installing whichever of these libraries is most appropriate
for your system, together with its header files.
For example, a libncurses-dev(el) or similar package.
```

Then I wonder which one I need, and maybe I am installing libraries with features that I am not using. In the last resort, I want to ask what what flags should I pass to the `./configure` and what libraries should I install first.

I am on `Linux fedora-acer 4.16.5-200.fc27.x86_64` using gnome shell on xorg.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried `pdumper` branch but for `tputs`, you need to install `ncurses-devel`

Following packages were required on f28 for successful compilation:

`autoconf
texinfo
gtk4-devel
gtk+-devel
libXaw-devel
libtiff-devel
giflib-devel
jpeglib-devel
gnutls-devel
ncurses-devel`